# How to use 'screen' to compile a project and give a notification when compilation is done?

Tags: 12.04, compiling

I am using "**Screen**" on Ubuntu.

How can I use 'screen' to compile my project and give me a notification when compile is done whether the build is successful or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the screen is running on the same machine as your desktop, you can do

```
 make 2> make.errors ; notify-osd "Compilation done" "`tail -3 make.errors`"
```

or

```
(make && notify-send "Compilation finished" "Success") || notify-send "Compilation finished" "Failure"
```

If it is running on another system to which you connect over ssh, however, you will have to install a mailer that sends you an e-mail.